# Application menu Editor

Tags: linux, archlinux, gnome-3

How can I make changes to my main Application menu In Gnome3, Any configuration files Or any tool do this out There?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the alacarte the menu editor used to be exist in Gnome-2

I am on ArchLinux flow this:
[Menu Editing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Tips#Menu_Editing)

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by "main applications menu"? Are you referring to the 'Applications' section in the Activities Overview or do you have a GNOME Shell Extension which adds an applications menu to one of the panels?

In either case, they would be based on the [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) and the [Desktop Menu Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/) from freedesktop.org.

So, if you just need to manipulate which applications appear in which categories you would edit the `Categories` key in the applications' `.desktop` file.

You can use [Desktop Entry Editor](https://github.com/MicahCarrick/desktop-entry-editor) to edit `.desktop` files in a GUI (run it as root to edit desktop entries for applications installed to the system dirs `/usr/share/applications` and `/usr/local/share/applciations` and run it as a normal user to create your own custom application launchers in `~/.local/share/applications`.

You can also still use the GNOME 2-style menu editor in GNOME 3, `alacarte`, which is in the repos for most distros.

Comment: alacrate is the one I'm looking for, I just found it a few hours ago
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8642820/771300